# Whether can set the theme of ProjectA to ProjectB?

Tags: android

Whether can set the theme of ProjectA to ProjectB? how to modify framework to support it？
The code like that:

```
friendContext = this.createPackageContext("com.android.projecta",
            Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
Theme theme=friendContext.getTheme();
setTheme(theme);
```

There is not api like: setTheme with Theme object.

This idea is not so unreasonable or can not be realized?

Comment: Others have tried getTheme().setTo(otherContext.getTheme()), but I don't think that will work, as the same named resources will have different generated ids.